# Firefox extension panels - require is not defined?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to load an html panel/popup that will serve as a menu for my Extension.

I succeeded loading it using (more or less):

```
var ifr = document.createElement("iframe");
ifr.setAttribute("type", "chrome");
ifr.setAttribute("style", "width: 200px; height: 300px;");

ifr.setAttribute("src", url);
IROB_MENU.mnu.appendChild(ifr);
IROB_MENU.mnu.openPopup(navbar, "before_end", 0, 0, false, false);
```

Now I can't find a way to communicate with it, for some reason postMessage didn't work.

I read somewhere that if you open a panel you can assign a handler for messages on it and can use ports to communicate so I tried:

```
var MeteoPanel = require("panel").Panel({
    width: 320,
    height: 170,
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url('panel.js'),
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentScript: "SOMESCRIPT",
    contentURL: self.data.url('thecontent.html'),
    onMessage: function (item) {
      console.log('message : "' + item + '"');
    }
});
```

But I get an error msg saying that 'require' is undefined :|

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using `require` from `lib/main` in your addon, or is it in a content script itself? `require` needs to be used from within the 'main' add on code

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to download the Add-On SDK. You can find instructions on installation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Installation